# Datastax DevCenter 1.5.0 connection to remote Cassandra 2.1.4 with SSL and CQL Version

Tags: cassandra, windows-7-x64, datastax, cql3

Just installed 64 bit DevCenter 1.5.0 on my Windows 7x64 pc.  Now I am trying to connect DevCenter to our Apache Cassandra installation on a remote server.  Within DevCenter, I'm getting an error when I try to connect to a remote Cassandra installation.  The message from the error log is

```
!ENTRY Connection # open 4 0 2016-05-19 08:03:02.529
!MESSAGE com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: host.domain.com/###.##.##.###:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [host.domain.com/###.##.##.###:9042] Cannot connect))
```

I can however connect command line using cqlsh and it shows

```
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.14 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3.
```

In my cqlshrc file - I have to specify [cql] version = 3.2.1 and the certificate to make the connection function.
From what I have read - to make DevCenter connect - I had to do a couple of things

1)  Create a truststore for the certificate and reference it in the connection properties with the password - and that seems to be ok I believe (info from the DataStax site)

2)  The second thing I needed to do was change the cassandra.yaml file in C:\Program Files\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf - change the rpc_address to the host.domain.com and verify start_native_transport: true (StackOverflow)

I am not sure what I am missing - to successfully connect DataStax DevCenter on my windows 7 machine to the apache cassandra installation on a remote server (host.domain.com).

Comment: Have you checked this blog post? http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-to-connect-devcenter-to-an-ssl-enabled-cassandra-cluster

Comment: Yes I did check that blog - and did perform those steps.